# Any open source API to get near by restaurants at a particular location in India?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm working on a mobile application to get restaurant details like their geolocation and ratings for users located in **INDIA..** I thought of using Zomato. Since its not free now, can someone show pointers to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about Bing Maps API?
[there](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/features.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Arman,Bing maps api is good. But It is not that accurate in india. So I kinda need location based services api which works perfectly in india..

Comment: I my mind don't lie, Bing Maps have layers with many services.

Comment: Russian Yandex.Maps have social mode - layers, which created by people and shows local places and objects. I think, Bing and OSM must provide API for something similar.

Comment: ,,Thank you. Will go with BingMapsAPI